# How to wrap callback function in other callback function and call from there?

Tags: javascript, callback, typescript

Following is my code :

```
        var me = this;
        gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: client, scope: scope, immediate: true }, function (authResult: any) {
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                me.accessToken = authResult.access_token;

            } else {

              //TODO : show error in front end
            }
        });
```

when i use callback function like this.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: client, scope: scope, immediate: true }, AuthResult);

function AuthResult(authResult: any) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    me.accessToken = authResult.access_token;

                } else {

                  //TODO : show error in front end
                }
```

**I dont get the me property in that callback function**

How i can **wrap the callback function in other callback** function where i can get the scope also in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fat arrow:

```
    gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: client, scope: scope, immediate: true },AuthResult);

    const AuthResult = (authResult: any) => {
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                this.accessToken = authResult.access_token;

            } else {
              //TODO : show error in front end
            }
```

## More

Don't use `.bind` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html at least not yet

Comment: if i have to use the same work in javascript instead of typescript. Bind would be fine then or harmful as described in link too/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
gapi.auth.authorize(..., AuthResult.bind(this));

function AuthResult(...) {
  // use `this` instead of `me`
}
```

See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)